# Convert comma separated non json string to json

Tags: postgresql

Below is the value of a string in a text column.

```
select col1 from tt_d_tab;

'A:10000000,B:50000000,C:1000000,D:10000000,E:10000000'
```

I'm trying to convert it into json of below format.

```
'{"A": 10000000,"B": 50000000,"C": 1000000,"D": 10000000,"E": 10000000}'
```

Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your key is a single capital letter as in your example

```
select concat('{',regexp_replace('A:10000000,B:50000000,C:1000000,D:10000000,E:10000000','([A-Z])','"\1"','g'),'}')::json json_field;
```

A more general case with any number of letters caps or not

```
select concat('{',regexp_replace('Ac:10000000,BT:50000000,Cs:1000000,D:10000000,E:10000000','([a-zA-Z]+)','"\1"','g'),'}')::json json_field;
```

Comment: It's just an example, the key might have more than single letter as well.

Comment: Then just modify the regular expression.

Comment: The second query is the exact solution I'm looking for. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

If you know that neither the keys nor values will have `:` or `,` characters in them, you can write

```sql
select json_object(regexp_split_to_array(col1,'[:,]')) from tt_d_tab;
```

This splits the string on every colon and comma, then interprets the result as key/value pairs.

If the string manipulation gets any more complicated, SQL may not be the ideal tool for the job, but it's still doable, either by this method or by converting the string into the form you need directly and then casting it to json with `::json`.

Comment: Key will be string and the value will always be a number. how can I set the value part without double-quotes?

Comment: I don't think there's a simple way to do that with splitting, you're probably better off with https://stackoverflow.com/a/73614316/1747583.